# Generating intermediate .i files (preprocessed files) when compiling Ubuntu-8.04

Tags: linux-kernel, compilation, intermediate-code

I'm building ubuntu-8.04 with gcc 3.4 and I need to generate the .i files, which are the output of the gcc preprocessor. I have tried adding the --save-temps flag but this only generates the .i files for the top level directory, i.e. source, and does not seem to get passed recursively to the child directories. I also tried the -E flag, which is supposed to output preprocessed files and stop compilation, but this did not generate the files either.

I'm specifically looking to generate the .i files for the source in net/core.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

There is no support for bulk preprocessing.

For single file use "make net/core/foo.i"

For bulk, workaround is "make C=2 CHECK="cc -E"".

Answer (score 0):

I know that is an old post, but maybe can be useful; for me this works:
`gcc -E filename.c -o outputfile.i`